# How to alter AWS RDS tables in `mysql` schema?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I want to alter tables like `mysql.rds_sysinfo`, `mysql.rds_monitor`, `mysql.rds_heartbeat2` which belong to `mysql` schema.

The alter sql for that is:
`ALTER TABLE mysql.rds_sysinfo ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;`

But when I run it some error appears:
`Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' to database 'mysql'`

So how can I get access to alter the such tables of AWS RDS?

Comment: What is your goal?  Would it suffice to write a read-only VIEW in front of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never be allowed to alter any tables used by RDS Services. They are managed by Amazon.

I see you logged in as `admin@'%'` but Amazon has shielded their source-compiled version of mysqld from  allowing anyone to change their managed tables.

Even if `SHOW GRANTS;` says you have all privileges, you really don't. I have mentioned this years ago (See [Confused by GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* (...) WITH GRANT OPTION](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104626/confused-by-grant-all-privileges-on-with-grant-option/104636#104636)).

If those tables need to be in another row format, Amazon will do that.